# keystroke to return to lost X session

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, x-windows, text-mode

While at my console I accidentally hit Ctrl+Alt+F2, which replaced my screens with a text-mode login prompt, as it should.  From that shell, I see that `/usr/bin/X` and my previous shells and processes are still running.

To once again show my X-windows session, that I'd started long ago in the usual way right after booting,
what keys should I hit (or what signal should I send, where)?

Comment: It should have been `Ctrl-Alt-F2` that you hit. To return to your main X session, you want `Ctrl-Alt-F7`. If you have somehow configured your system so that `Alt-F2` switches terminals, then I guess `Alt-F7` would switch back.

Comment: Enter that as an answer, and I'll accept it.  How embarrassing... I stopped trying after 5, and 7 worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 14.04 the default key-stroke to invoke a virtual terminal is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd>, where `n` is the number of the virtual terminal desired.

Also by default, there are is an allocation of six virtual terminals, controlled by the `agetty` instances. See `ps -C agetty` - at least, that's the command on 18.04 that I am now using, though the instances don't appear until after each <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd>. I'm afraid I can't remember how it was handled in 14.04, but it will have been something similar.

The main X session is therefore restored by invoking virtual terminal 7 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.